# How to get database data in listview after insert new data in android

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

Here's the scenario like, I have a disease table in SQLITE database it contains a list of disease. While i enter into the new activity,i will get the datas from disease table and load it in listview. Now,in listview page..im adding new disease in disease table. After insert data,how to refresh the listvew.
Any Suggestions??

Answer (score 1):

You have to notify the adapter for changes on data so it will refresh the listview. In your case, call something like `cursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after doing the insertion.

Answer (score 0):

You can add newly inserted data into your listview's dataset that is your arraylist or any other object and then call notifyDataSetChanged of the listview's adapter.

Post more code for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use swipe-to-refresh and fetch the data from database meanwhile. Fetch the new data in OnRefreshListener and then update UI.

Answer (score 0):

You should notify the adapter that the data has changed and then should refresh the listView. below is a sample:

```
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
myListView.invalidateViews();
myListView.refreshDrawableState();
```