# I implemented delete button on ListView it is working but item is there after click how it will remove from there

Tags: android

I implemented delete button on ListView it is working but item is there after click how it will remove from there. I am sending matriID_to and matriID_by from POST method. When I clicked on remove button then Log.e message is printed and item is deleted from database but it was not deleted from item. I need that row should be hide when click on button.

```
public class Shortlisted_custom  extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private static final String deleteURL = "http://10.0.2.2/xp/ajax_call.php?action=remove_shortlisted";
private static final String KEY_MATRI_ID_TO="matriID_to";
private static final String KEY_MATRI_ID_BY="matriID_by";

SessionManager session;
public String matri_id_to, matri_id_by, str_gender,strEI;
int selectedPosition;

private final String[] ids;
private String[] ages;
private String[] heights;
public String[] communities;
public String[] castes;
public String[] educations;
public String[] occupations;
public String[] incomes;
public String[] pics;
public String[] locations;
public String[] shortlist;
public String[] expressinterest;

private Activity context;

public Shortlisted_custom(Activity context, String[] ids, String[] ages, String[] heights, String[] communities, String[] castes, String[] educations, String[] occupations, String[]incomes, String[]pics, String[] locations, String[] shortlist, String[] expressinterest) {
    super(context, R.layout.custom_shortlist,ids);
    this.ids = ids;
    this.ages = ages;
    this.heights = heights;
    this.communities = communities;
    this.castes = castes;
    this.educations = educations;
    this.occupations = occupations;
    this.incomes = incomes;
    this.pics = pics;
    this.locations = locations;
    this.context = context;
    this.shortlist = shortlist;
    this.expressinterest = expressinterest;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_shortlist, null, true);
```

Session class instance

```
    session = new SessionManager(getContext());
    session.checkLogin();
```

Get user data from session

```
   HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
    matri_id_by = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_EMAIL);
    str_gender = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_GENDER);


    TextView textViewId = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewId);
    TextView textViewName = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
    textViewId.setText(ids[position]);
    textViewName.setText( ages[position]+" years"+" , "+heights[position]+" cm"+", "+communities[position]+" : "+castes[position]+" , "+educations[position]+" , "+occupations[position]+" , "+incomes[position]+", "+locations[position]);
```

Remove Button

```
    Button btnremove =(Button) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.btnRemove);
    btnremove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            matri_id_to=ids[position];
            selectedPosition = position;
            delete();
        }
    });


    return listViewItem;
}

public void delete(){
    StringRequest stringRequest1 = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, deleteURL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.e("response********",response);
            if(response.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
                Log.e("M deleted","This item has been deleted");
            }
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put(KEY_MATRI_ID_BY,matri_id_by);
            params.put(KEY_MATRI_ID_TO,matri_id_to);
            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest1);
  }
 }
```

Comment: On delete success delete item from list and call notifydatasetChangerd();

Comment: How to delete from list and where I will put this method

Comment: inside onResponse method delete clicked item from your adapter list

Comment: you need to remove that item from your arraylist as well

Comment: how to remove from there

Comment: you need to notify the `adapter` that some changes has been made to the list and refresh the listView, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45771219/4116560

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this use your `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after delete operation

```
 Button btnremove =(Button) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.btnRemove);
btnremove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        matri_id_to=ids[position];
        selectedPosition = position;
        delete();
        // remove your item here from the your array like this

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(ids));
        list.remove(matri_id_to);
        ids = list.toArray(new String[0])
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Comment: notifydatasetChangerd(); this method showing error "Can not resolve method"

Comment: is this btnremove in your adapter class or in your activity

Comment: btnremove is in adapter class

Comment: than just use `notifyDataSetChanged();` @VikasGodiyal

Comment: yes I used this but Item is there no change on itemlist

Comment: @VikasGodiyal your need to remove that item from your list after performing `delete operation ` than call `notifyDataSetChanged();` i hope your get it now

Comment: I have used notifyDataSetChanged() but list is not refreshing on click remove button

Comment: your have to remove that item postiion from your arrays as well than cal         `notifyDataSetChanged()` @VikasGodiyal

Comment: yes make sure after the success response from the delete api you are removing the same item from the list and then notifyDataSetChanged(). also you can use adapter.removeItem(position).

Comment: @VikasGodiyal  import this package `import java.util.List;`

Comment: and you have to use arraylist insted of seperate array @VikasGodiyal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152700/discussion-between-nilesh-rathod-and-vikas-godiyal).

Comment: we cannot chat there for privacy proxy "This site is blocked due to content filtering."

Comment: ohk @VikasGodiyal

Comment: @Nilesh I have done that code please check edited code but It is refreshing whole page not only that item which I want to do delete